# Get substring between 3rd colon and 4th colon

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have strings in the below pattern:

```
ab:ab:ab:1:ab
ac:ac:ac:2:ac
ad:ad:ad:3:ad
```

I have to extract the string between the `3rd colon` and the `4th colon`.

For the above example strings, the results would be `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`.

What is a short way in Java using string functions to extract it?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/4480774#4480774

Comment: Just any piece of code that works. I meant shorter rather than efficient.

Comment: Just use `split`. Which is neither time nor space efficient, as it uses a regex and makes copies of parts of the string you con't care about.

Comment: Your examples all have the part you want to extract in position 9.  Is that always going to be the case?  Or will it vary? `abcd:e:fghijk:123:trwe` for example?

Comment: "What is a short way in Java using string functions to extract it?" - The call to a dedicated method. I mean, if the correct abstraction of your requirement is indeed "extract the string between the 3rd colon and the 4th colon", and you want to write fast efficient code, it's gonna be a few lines in said method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split by ":" and get the fourth element:

something like:

```
Stream.of("ab:ab:ab:1:ab", "ac:ac:ac:2:ac", "ad:ad:ad:3:ad")
      .map(s -> s.split(":")[3])
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Note to readers: To collect results, replace `.forEach` with `.toList`.

Answer (score 1):

And as an alternative, replace the entire string with the desired item via a capture.

- `(?:.*?:){3}` - non capturing group of three reluctant strings followed by a `:`
- `(.*?)` - the capture of the target between 3rd and 4th colon.
- `.*$` - the rest of the string to the end.
- `$1` - the reference to the first (and only) capture group

```
String[] data = { "ab:ab:ab:1:ab",
 "ac:ac:ac:2:ac",
 "ad:ad:ad:3:ad"};

for (String str : data) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?:.*?:){3}(.*?):.*$","$1"));
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
```